# How do you distribute your app across multiple servers using EC2?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, scaling, autoscaling

For the first time I am developing an app that requires quite a bit of scaling, I have never had an application need to run on multiple instances before.

How is this normally achieved? Do I cluster SQL servers then mirror the programming across all servers and use load balancing?

Or do I separate out the functionality to run some on one server some on another?

Also how do I push out code to all my EC2 windows instances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer - I'm not going to mention any Windows specifics because I have always worked on Unix machines. These guidelines are fairly generic.

This is a subjective question and everyone would tailor one's own system in a unique style. Here are a few guidelines I follow.

If it's a web application, separate the presentation (front-end), middleware (APIs) and database layers. A sliced architecture scales the best as compared to a monolithic application.

1. **Database** - Amazon provides excellent and highly available services (unless you are on us-east availability zone) for SQL and NoSQL data stores. You might want to check out [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) for Relational databases and [DynamoDb](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) for NoSQL. Both scale well and you need not worry about managing and load sharding/clustering your data stores once you launch them.
2. **Middleware APIs** - This is a crucial part. It is important to have a set of APIs (preferably REST, but you could pretty much use anything here) which expose your back-end functionality as a service. A service oriented architecture can be scaled very easily to cater multiple front-facing clients such as web, mobile, desktop, third-party widgets, etc. **Middleware APIs should typically NOT be where your business logic is processed**, most of it (or all of it) should be translated to database lookups/queries for higher performance. These services could be load balanced for high availability. Amazon's [Elastic Load Balancers](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (ELB) are good for starters. If you want to get into some more customization like blocking traffic for certain set of IP addresses, performing [Blue/Green deployments](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html), then maybe you should consider HAProxy load balancers deployed to separate instances.
3. **Front-end** - This is where your presentation layer should reside. It should avoid any direct database queries except for the ones which are limited to the scope of the front-end e.g.: a simple Redis call to get the latest cache keys for front-end fragments. Here is where you could pretty much perform a lot of caching, right from the service calls to the front-end fragments. You could use [AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for static assets delivery and [AWS ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) for your cache store. ElastiCache is nothing but a managed memcached cluster. You should even consider load balancing the front-end nodes behind an ELB.

All this can be bundled and deployed with AutoScaling using [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). It currently supports ASP .NET, PHP, Python, Java and Ruby containers. AWS Elastic Beanstalk still has it's own limitations but is a very cool way to manage your infrastructure with the least hassle for monitoring, scaling and load balancing.

**Tip**: Identifying the read and write intensive areas of your application helps a lot. You could then go ahead and slice your infrastructure accordingly and perform required optimizations with a read or write focus at a time.

To sum it all, Amazon AWS has pretty much everything you could possibly use to craft your server topology. It's upon you to choose components.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

This will depend on the requirements you have. But as a general guideline (I am assuming a website) I would separate db, webserver, caching server etc to different instance(s) and use [s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)(+[cloudfont](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)) for static assets. I would also make sure that some proper rate limiting is in place so that only legitimate load is on the infrastructure.

For RDBMS server I might setup a master-slave db setup ([RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) makes this easier), use db sharding etc. DB cluster solutions also exists which will be more complex to setup but simplifies database access for the application programmer. I would also check all the db queries and the tune db/sql queries accordingly. In some cases pure NoSQL type databases might be better than RDBMS or a mix of both where the application switches between them depending on the data required.

For webserver I will setup a loadbalancer and then use autoscaling on the webserver instance(s) behind the loadbalancer. Something similar will apply for app server if any. I will also tune the web servers settings.

Caching server will also be separated into its on cluster of instance(s). [ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) seems like a nice service. Redis has comparable performance to memcache but has more features(like lists, sets etc) which might come in handy when scaling.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it would be, to have 1 server as the DB server with mysql running on it. All my data on memcached, which can span across multiple servers and my clients with a simple "if not on memcached, read from db, put it on memcached and return".

Memcached is very easy to scale, as compared to a DB. A db scaling takes a lot of administrative effort. Its a pain to get it right and working. So I choose memcached. Infact I have extra memcached servers up, just to manage downtime (if any of my memcached) servers.

My data is mostly read, and few writes. And when writes happen, I push the data to memcached too. All in all this works better for me, code, administrative, fallback, failover, loadbalancing way. All win. You just need to code a "little" bit better.

Clustering mysql is more tempting, as it seems more easy to code, deploy, maintain and keep up and performing. Remember mysql is harddisk based, and memcached is memory based, so by nature its much more faster (10 times atleast). And since it takes over all the read load from the db, your db config can be REALLY simple.

I really hope someone points to a contrary argument here, I would love to hear it.